# Parcel Error The Build Is Crashing: @parcel/transformer-js: (0 , _native.transform) is not a function

Tags: node.js, transform, parcel

The build was stable and I actually was not coding on my components. I just let it run. And in about an hour, it just crashed.

Here is the error:

```
 Build failed.

@parcel/transformer-js: (0 , _native.transform) is not a function

  TypeError: (0 , _native.transform) is not a function
      at Object.transform (/Users/josedmartinez/Documents/CODE CAREER FOUNDRY/OTHER 
  PROJECTS/myFaveFlixes6-client/node_modules/@parcel/transformer-js/lib/JSTransformer.js:378:31)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at async Transformation.runTransformer 
  (/Users/jxxxxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/parcel/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Transformation.js:653:5)
      at async Transformation.runPipeline 
  (/Users/jxxxxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/parcel/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Transformation.js:402:36)
      at async Transformation.runPipelines 
  (/Users/jxxxxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/parcel/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Transformation.js:265:40)
      at async Transformation.run 
  (/Users/jxxxxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/parcel/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Transformation.js:183:21)
      at async Object.run 
  (/Users/jxxxxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/parcel/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/requests/AssetRequest.js:122:7)
      at async RequestTracker.runRequest 
  (/Users/jxxxxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/parcel/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/RequestTracker.js:756:20)
      at async AssetGraphBuilder.runAssetRequest 
  (/Users/jxxxxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/parcel/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/requests/AssetGraphRequest.js:857:18)
      at async $b0fd219fea43bcac$export$2e2bcd8739ae039._runFn 
  (/Users/jxxxxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/parcel/node_modules/@parcel/utils/lib/index.js:33579:13)
```

I don't know if I need to show more code. I have a directory with REACT, Node, and Parcel installed with all the dependencies. I also have various components/files

Does anyone know why this happens with parcel?

Also, here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "myfaveflixes6-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A web app to collect your favorite movies.",
  "default": "src/index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/cheito70/myFaveFlixes6-client.git"
  },
  "author": "joe",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/cheito70/myFaveFlixes6-client/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/cheito70/myFaveFlixes6-client#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.2.0",
    "parcel": "^2.8.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
    "redux": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.8.0",
    "buffer": "^5.7.1",
    "process": "^0.11.10"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried npm update and it worked for me, seems like my project was outdated :)